# how to fix this issue that angular js ng-repeat shows only one element in the array of objects?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

i have a array of objects in the controller . when the controller invoked,ng-repeat shows all objects in the array as list.  works fine..
but when i push a new object first time into the array.  works fine.. it shows the object as well. when i push another object into array it doesn't show that object.how to fix this issue?
**Controller:**

```
 App.controller('teamController', function($scope,$http,$routeParams,$location,$filter) {
$scope.teammembers = [];});
```

**Directive:**`App.directive("searchableMultiselect", function($timeout) {
  return {
    templateUrl: 'angular/templates/team/teamdropdown.php',
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
      displayAttr: '@',
      allItems: '=',
    },link: function(scope, element, attrs) {});`

```
**Template:**

    <li ng-repeat="item in ::allItems track by $index">
```

**Frontend:**

```
<searchable-multiselect display-attr="name"
                                        all-items="teammembers" >
                                     </searchable-multiselect>
```

Answer (score 2):

you allow only one-way binding. need to change it to two-way binding. remove `::` in the `ng-repeat`

```
<li ng-repeat="item in allItems track by $index">
```

Comment: i want to avoid dublicates in that  array.. when i push the object into array it should not be dublicate.. have solution?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/remove-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript